# Laravel 5.4 not connecting to Maria DB in WTSERVER

Tags: php, mariadb, laravel-5.4

Recently started using the [WTServer](https://wtserver.wtriple.com/) installed in The Amazon WorkSpace.

So In a fresh install of laravel 5.4 ,

I tried to do

`php artisan migrate` in order to setup the laravel related Tables.

But I am getting following error .

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it.

I dumped the connection details like this in my controller.

```
if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
        {
             echo "connected successfully to database ".DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
        }
```

and it says that the connection is established fine.

But I try to do a SELECT /Insert/Delete anything in the table , It gives me `2002` error.

Any Idea what could have gone wrong

Thanks

Comment: Are your php application and MySQL server on the same instance?

Comment: did you get any answer yet?

Comment: @Naeem no bro didnt get

Comment: mine resolved. there was a mistake in my .env file for db connection string. you can also check if pdo_mysql installed using phpinfo()